# Swift mutable array parameters

Tags: swift, swift4, mutability

So I'm basically trying to mutate a parameter of a tuple variable and my code looks like this:

```
var tabsections: [(sectionTitle: String?, rows: [String])]
tabsections = [("2017", []),
               ("2018", [])]

var mutableMonths = ["2017-02", "2017-10", "2018-01"]

for section in tabsections {
    for month in mutableMonths {
        if section.sectionTitle == month.split(separator: "-").first?.string {
            section.rows.append((month.split(separator: "-").last?.string)!)  // "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type '[String]'"
            mutableMonths.removeFirst()
        }
    }
}
```

but I keep in getting the error

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type '[String]'

Then after specifying more the `section` variable while declaring the loop by replacing it by `(sectionTitle, rows)` the error changes into something like:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'rows' is a 'let' constant

I found answers talking about mutability such as this one but only for functions (where adding the keyword `inout` would fix it) but as a local variable I'm running out of ideas.

Am i missing something trivial here??

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that I know that a basic C based loop would do the trick such as

```
var i = 0
while i < tabsections.count {
    for month in mutableMonths {
        if tabsections[i].sectionTitle == month.split(separator: "-").first?.string {
            tabsections[i].rows.append((month.split(separator: "-").last?.string)!)
            mutableMonths.removeFirst()
        }
    }
    i += 1
}
```

But i was wondering if there was a more elegant/swifty way of doing so in Swift 4 since adding `var` in Swift 3 would do the trick.

Thanks!

Comment: Why `= []` if on the next line you'll assign it a different value?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. The original code was way more complicated so I just forgot to delete that part.

Comment: Well, you could simplify this a lot. Why are your months array mutable, and why are they strings? Dates are really difficult to work with as strings

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Its mutable. But as you are iterating over `tabsections`, `section` in for loop cannot change. 
If you write something like (before for loop)

```
tabsections[0].rows.append("2017-02")
```

It would work.

But inside for loop trying to change the member of array which you are iterating over might cause issues. Think like if you are developing a programming language. It helps in learning. If someone is iterating over an array and removes an element from the same array. How would the program state be? It would be like cutting the branch of the tree on which you yourself were sitting. :)

Comment: Thanks! You're right. And sorry, forgot to mention that I knew an C-like loop would work on this but I was looking for something more swifty since mutable `var` on loops was deprecated in Swift 4 (from what I understood).

Answer (score 0):

`section` is a `let` property, local to the scope of your `for` loop. You could try using `for var section in ...` instead, but you would still be making a local copy (Arrays are value types), which would require you to reassign it back into the right index of `tabsections` in order to change the data there.

Instead, I suggest you take a more functional approach:

```
func parse(dateString: String) -> (year: Int, month: Int) {
    let parts = dateString.split(separator: "-")
    return (year: Int(parts[0])!, month: Int(parts[1])!)
}

var mutableMonths = ["2017-02", "2017-10", "2018-01"]
let yearMonthPairs = mutableMonths.map(parse(dateString:))

let tabSections = Dictionary(grouping: yearMonthPairs, by: { $0.year })
    .mapValues{ $0.map{ $0.month } }
```

This produces a dictionary of type `[Int: [Int]]` mapping years to months within those years, all as `Int`, so they're easier to work with. When you need to display this as a table, you can just call `.map{ year, months in (section: String(year), row: months.map(String.init)) }` on it, and it will produce the same array of tuples that your initial code was using

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the error is that while iterating your first for loop the 'section' variable is let type.So, the solution would be:

```
var tabsections: [(sectionTitle: String?, rows: [String])] = []
tabsections = [("2017", []),
           ("2018", [])]

var mutableMonths = ["2017-02", "2017-10", "2018-01"]

for (index,section) in tabsections.enumerated() {
for month in mutableMonths {
if section.sectionTitle == month.split(separator: "-").first?.string {
        tabsections[index].rows.append((month.split(separator: "-").last?.string)!)  // "getting error as section is let type variable"
        mutableMonths.removeFirst()
  }
 }
}
```